# Unable to pack a Nuget Package on VSTS Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework'

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

On running 'pack' I am getting the following error...

```
2017-07-05T10:37:09.7762333Z ##[section]Starting: NuGet pack
2017-07-05T10:37:09.7762333Z ==============================================================================
2017-07-05T10:37:09.7762333Z Task         : NuGet
2017-07-05T10:37:09.7762333Z Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
2017-07-05T10:37:09.7762333Z Version      : 2.0.3
2017-07-05T10:37:09.7762333Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-07-05T10:37:09.7762333Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
2017-07-05T10:37:09.7762333Z ==============================================================================
2017-07-05T10:37:10.9664575Z Downloading: https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.0.0/nuget.exe
2017-07-05T10:37:11.0954621Z Caching tool: NuGet 4.0.0 x64
2017-07-05T10:37:11.1084622Z Using version: 4.0.0
2017-07-05T10:37:11.1094622Z Found tool in cache: NuGet 4.0.0 x64
2017-07-05T10:37:11.1214629Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2017-07-05T10:37:11.1634626Z Active code page: 65001
2017-07-05T10:37:11.2234637Z Attempting to pack file: d:\a\1\s\src\Esoterix\Esoterix.csproj
2017-07-05T10:37:11.2294640Z [command]d:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64\nuget.exe pack d:\a\1\s\src\Esoterix\Esoterix.csproj -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory d:\a\1\a -Properties Configuration=release -version 1.0.0-CI-201765-103711 -Verbosity Detailed
2017-07-05T10:37:12.3087180Z NuGet Version: 4.0.0.2283
2017-07-05T10:37:12.3187144Z Attempting to build package from 'Esoterix.csproj'.
2017-07-05T10:37:12.7569409Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.1.1012.6693' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
2017-07-05T10:37:15.3118046Z Packing files from 'd:\a\1\s\src\Esoterix\bin\release\netcoreapp1.1'.
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7119285Z Add file 'd:\a\1\s\src\Esoterix\bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\Esoterix.dll' to package as 'lib\netcoreapp1.1\Esoterix.dll'
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7959331Z System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework'.
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject.GetMetadata[T](String key)
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at NuGet.ProjectManagement.PackagesConfigNuGetProject..ctor(String folderPath, Dictionary`2 metadata)
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , Dictionary`2 )
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.AddDependencies(Dictionary`2 packagesAndDependencies)
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.ProcessDependencies(PackageBuilder builder)
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder(String basePath, NuGetVersion version, String suffix, Boolean buildIfNeeded, PackageBuilder builder)
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromProjectFile(String path)
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
2017-07-05T10:37:15.7969309Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
2017-07-05T10:37:15.8259323Z ##[error]Error: d:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64\nuget.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-07-05T10:37:15.8259323Z ##[error]An error ocurred while trying to pack the files.
2017-07-05T10:37:15.8289336Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet pack
```

It seems that everything is picked up fine up to this point so I'm a bit stuck . Any ideas welcome.

Comment: What's the agent are you use? Did the project migrate from VS2015 to VS2017 and can you upload your project to one drive?

Comment: The correct answer belongs to @praveena-m -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/53614798/2412853. Sorry, I am not allowed to comment to your post. Additionally, you may want to stick with a Version <5.0.0. In order to do that, you can specify `4.x >=4.3`. The problem seems to be resolved in 4.3.0.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In VSTS I used "**dotnet pack**" instead of "**nuget pack**". So this problem was resolved.

To publish nuget lib on VSTS, I choiced the following plugins sequence:

- Get sources
- nuget restore
- dotnet build
- dotnet pack
- nuget push

Comment: I think you need also to use "dotnet push"  instead of  "nuget push"

Comment: This issue has been resolved in the newer version of the nuget. I got it working by setting the nuget version to 4.9.1

Answer (score 19):

[image: Using Nuget 4.9.1 version resolved resolved my issue.]

Using Nuget 4.9.1 version resolved my issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer so that you can stick with executing Nuget commands rather than resorting to the dotnet.exe command set.

Comment: I have got into same error when when I use  nuget pack ,nuget push to publish .net core library project . I have  included use nuget 4.9.1 task at the top then  Error got resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue with my .net standard 2.0 class library I was pack into a nuget package. Here is a screenshot of the step you need to add to replace nuget pack step.

Step Type To Add
[image: Step Type To Add]

Here is how I configured the step
[image: Here is how I configured the step]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue using the Nuget pack item built in to VSTS. I swapped it out for a Command Line element to call dotnet pack instead and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

For pack command to work, you need to ensure that the csproj has the following tags:

```
<PackageId>*qualified_package_name*</PackageId>
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

This is particularly relevant if you've migrated from an old-style CSPROJ file

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when I want to pack .net core library project. Adding Use Nuget 4.9.1 resolved my issue.
[image]

Comment: Please make more obvious why you chose to create an answer instead of upvoting those with the seemingly same content, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53614798/7733418