# Error NU5012 - nuget pack unable to find path (/bin/release/MyProject/bin/release)

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-cli

I'm trying to update my nuget package by running the command `nuget pack -properties Configuration=Release` but this gives me the following error:

> Unable to find 'bin/Release/{project-name}/bin/Release'. Mae sure the project has been built

I'm not quite sure why it goes to my Release folder and then continues to go down to another Release folder as this doesn't exist? I'm quite lost here, and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Can you share your project file? Nothing to really go on from what you have given right now.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sorry, but this has been a while. I forgot to answer this SO with my solution :/

Answer (score 41):

**TL;DR**

For the new `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` .csproj file format, use [`dotnet pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x) to build NuGet packages, even if they target .Net Framework or if the project is multi-targeted. Run this from the directory containing your `.csproj` (and optionally a `.nuspec`)

```
dotnet pack MyProject.csproj -c Release
```

Note that by default `dotnet pack` places the output `.nupkg` in the `/bin/Release` folder, which is different from the current default folder where older `nuget pack` placed it.

I would suggest you don't create explicit `.nuspec` files for the new `.csproj` formats, since most settings can be set in the "Packages" tab of the new Project format. However, if you do have a `.nuspec`, then `dotnet pack` will also combine any `.nuspec` file matching the project name, allowing for the `$` symbol substitution from the version and metadata set in your `.csproj`.

**More Detail**

I also experienced this problem - in previous versions, I typically use to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14808085) to pack against a `.csproj` with the `.nuspec` file of the same name, so that I can use all of the $ tokens like `$id$`, `$version$`.

However when attempting this against the newer `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` csproj formats:

```
nuget pack {MyProject}.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release
```

I received the same error (note the "duplication" of `bin\release`):

> Error NU5012: Unable to find 'bin\Release{MyProject}\bin\Release\'. Make sure the project has been built.

And if I tried packing against a `.nuspec` containing symbols (NuGet Version: 4.7.1.5393)

```
nuget pack {MyProject}.nuspec -Prop Configuration=Release
```

I just get the [unhelpful message](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2714) because nuget isn't able to resolve the $ tokens automatically.

> Value cannot be null or an empty string.
>   Parameter name: value

However, by using dotnet pack instead of nuget

```
dotnet pack MyProject.csproj -c Release
```

I get to where I want to be, i.e. a multi-targeted NuGet package with the $ symbols in the `.nuspec` correctly synchronized from the `.csproj` (you can verify this by opening up the `.nupkg` file in e.g. 7zip and examining the final `.nuspec` file in the package root)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on a multi-targeted project (targetting both net452 and netstandard2.0).

My fix/hack was to add 'TargetFramework=net452' to the list of properties passed to Nuget, and manually adding the netstandard2.0-output to the files-section in the .nuspec-file

Hope someone finds a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Part of Rune's answer (setting `TargetFramework=net471` NuGet property)

and using NuGet version 4.9.1 (instruction here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53614798/1813219)

was a way to go for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just solved the problem on my end. Nuget may not find hidden dll.  Here is my solution:

- Build the project;
- Show all files in visual studio so you can see the hidden files, so that you can see the dll under bin folder;
- Right click, open folder in file explorer, then copy it to current folder let them replace/ Or unhidden the files;
- Do "Nuget Pack" again.