# How to cache the project.assets.json for each project from a solution in AzureDevOps Pipelines?

Tags: c#, caching, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-delivery

My solution(.sln) contains contains 21 projects and the `nuget restore` takes a lot of time(4m and 56s).

I am trying to cache the `nuget packages` for faster restore.

I've successfully cached the `/.nuget/packages` and it caches correctly but when the build runs it tries to access the `project.assets.json` for every project in solution and I get the following error:
`error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'd:\a\1\s\src\Project\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [d:\a\1\s\src\Project\Project.csproj]`

I've found from the Microsoft community support forums that I need to cache also the `project.assets.json` for every project... But how? The cache task doesn't support wildcards to recursively search through each project's `project.assets.json`.

Another solution would be to write 21 cache tasks with the exact path for each project, but this doesn't look right... maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Thanks!

EDIT here is my  auzre-pipelines.yml:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  configuration: Release
  NUGET_PACKAGES: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages
  CACHE_RESTORED: 'false'

- task: UseGitVersion@5
  displayName: 'Install GitVersion5'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'
    additionalArguments: '/output buildserver -config .\GitVersion.yml'

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install NuGet 5.3.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.3.x'

- task: Cache@2
   inputs:
     key: 'v1 | nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"'
     path: $(NUGET_PACKAGES)
     cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED

 - task: NuGetCommand@2
   inputs:
     command: 'restore'
     condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')
     restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
     feedsToUse: 'select'
     vstsFeed: 'a-dummy-feed'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/t:Restore'
    platform: 'any cpu'
    configuration: 'Release'
    clean: true
    logProjectEvents: false

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Generate .nupkg'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'UseGitVersion.GitVersion.NuGetVersion

 - task: NuGetCommand@2
   displayName: 'Push .nupkg to AzureArtifacts Feed'
   inputs:
     command: 'push'
     packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
     nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
     publishVstsFeed: 'a-dummy-feed'
     publishPackageMetadata: false
     allowPackageConflicts: true
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem showing the same error message. The root cause in my case was that not all the projects in my solution were set up to generate a `packages.lock.json` file.

It was in the projects where the `packages.lock.json` file was not present that `dotnet build` was complaining of not being able to find the `project.assets.json` file.

The solution to my problem was to enable the generation of a nuget lock file across all projects in my solution. Here's what I did, step by step.

1. Placed a [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) file at the root folder for my solution, containing this:

   ```
   <Project>
     <PropertyGroup>
       <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
       <DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>true</DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>
     </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
2. Cleaned my solution and rebuilt it to generate all the individual  `packages.lock.json` files. If you try this but files are not generated for some projects, try closing Visual Studio and re-opening it before rebuilding.
3. Added the `Build.Directory.props` file and all `packages.lock.json` files to git and committed them.

PS - I have a slightly different key in my cache task inputs:

```
    key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**'
```

This makes the task generate a cache for every project in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message,  the project.assets.json file doesn’t exist in the path.

You could try to add the `/t:Restore` in the **MSBuild Arguments**.

[image: Arguments]

Then the project.assets.json file will be automatically added during the build process.

[image: result]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks the VSBuild@1 task now works, but my nuget pack task is failing with the following error: Error NU5012: Unable to find 'd:\a\1\s\src\App\Project\bin\Release\Project.dll'. Make sure the project has been built.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find 'd:\a\1\s\src\App\Project\bin\Release\Project.dll'. Make sure the project has been built.

Comment: You could try to use the "dotnet pack" task. This [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815070/error-nu5012-nuget-pack-unable-to-find-path-bin-release-myproject-bin-releas) may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your time Kevin, but because of other issues with this pipeline, I ended up recreating the pipeline from scratch without using the Cache task as it didn't minimize the build time, you can read more about it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1034379/how-to-cache-the-projectassetsjson-for-each-projec.html

Comment: Hi @David Glad to know that you have found the suitable method to achieve your requirements.